# java error not a statement and ';' expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Fairly new to Java and I cannot understand why I keep getting these errors. Can anyone assist with this? Here's where the error is:

```
if (paramInt == 1) Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
new StringBuilder().append("/").append(paramString2).append("/").toString());

public static String downloadFile(String paramString1, String paramString2, int paramInt)
{
    try
    {
        File localFile = new File(paramString2);
        if (localFile.exists()) {
            localFile.delete();
        }
        URLConnection localURLConnection = new URL(paramString1).openConnection();
        FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(paramString2));
        InputStream localInputStream = localURLConnection.getInputStream();
        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[localURLConnection.getContentLength()];

        int j = 0;
        int i;
        while ((i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) > -1) {
            localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);
            j += i;
        }
        String str = new StringBuilder().append(" ").append(localFile.length()).append(" ").append(paramString2).toString();
        localInputStream.close();
        localFileOutputStream.close();
        try
        {
            if (paramInt == 1) Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new StringBuilder().append("/").append(paramString2).append("/").toString()); 
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
        }
        return str;
    } catch (IOException localIOException) {
        localIOException.printStackTrace();
    }
    return paramString1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code so SO picks up all of it? It's a bit difficult to read right now.

Comment: Repeat after me: "I shall strive to use braces for every flow-control statement [until such a time as I am a Java Expert]."

Comment: And *where* are the errors? You've posted a lot of code and very little description...

Comment: Looks like you are missing a opening paren after `exec`

Comment: That's not the only... look at `if (paramInt == 1) Process localProcess ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're not using the localProcess object here, so just get rid of it. make this line

```
 if (paramInt == 1) Process localProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new StringBuilder().append("/").append(paramString2).append("/").toString());
```

just read as:

```
if (paramInt == 1) Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new StringBuilder().append("/").append(paramString2).append("/").toString());
```

if you need to use the Process instance, declare it before the if statement and then assign it in the if  statement.

try using an editor like Eclipse or NetBeans, they will help you out quite a bit.

Comment: Even better, don't make it one line. Use braces and indent.